# Adding a padding 0 to a SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server

With SQL Server 2014, I have a nvarchar(10) column with values like this

```
9998
03345
05567
6675
```

I need to add a left padded "0" to all the cells that are 4 digits long so that all values are 5 digits.

How do I write an update that will take into account the width of the current value?

```
update MyTable set MyField= RIGHT('00000' + ?????, 5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `RIGHT`:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000' + <string>, 5)
```

Your `UPDATE` statement would look like this:

```
UPDATE <Table>
    SET <column> = RIGHT('00000' + <column>, 5)
```

You could add a `WHERE` clause to filter all rows with `LEN < 5`

```
WHERE LEN(<column>) < 5
```

Comment: But how would I update the field with the new value?